# Why is my htaccess rule not rewriting the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok so i have this url in my opencart application and it works well

```
http://site.com/index.php?route=information/contact
```

but the clients hates the url and wants

```
http://site.com/contact
```

i figured i could just do this in my htaccess and all would be good but visiting the url i get nothing

```
RewriteRule ^(contact)$ index.php?route=information/contact  [L,QSA]
```

any ideas

here is my htacess

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^contact$ /index.php?route=information/contact  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: So what happens when you visit http://site.com/contact? A 404?

Comment: If so, check your apache error log.. It will tell you what exactly it is trying to look for and is not able to find..

Comment: I don't see `RewriteEngine on` at the top of the file.

Comment: its there i just didnt paste it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the parenthesis

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ index.php?route=information/contact  [L,QSA]
```

your .htaccess should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^contact$ /index.php?route=information/contact  [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: that is what I do for my servers, you put: RewriteEngine On before this rule right? you have any rules before?

Comment: you need: RewriteEngine On before RewriteBase /

Comment: i have a conflicting rule RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA] can i still have this rule and but add an except on contact so the other rule can work

Comment: yes you need to add this "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact$" right before: "RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]" and you add the one I suggested before these 2

Comment: awesome...thanks again....one last thing...i have another can i do login also like contact so this line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(contact|login)$

Comment: @BookOfZeus let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2834/discussion-between-tamer-and-bookofzeus)

Comment: thanks the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact$ fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

Is mod_rewrite enabled?  Also, you might have to add

`RewriteEngine on`

before your RewriteRules

Answer (score 2):

[[OpenCart] Enable URL Rewriting for SEO](http://www.programmingfacts.com/opencart-enable-url-rewriting-for-seo/)

1. Login into Admin Control Panel
2. Select Admin > Configuration > Settings > Server
3. Select “SEO URL” option to yes.
4. You are done.

Comment: i have a conflicting rule RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA] can i still have this rule and but add an except on contact so the other rule can work

Comment: That conflicting rule is messing up everything, I've updated the answer, can you try the new solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a / before index.php

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ /index.php?route=information/contact  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i see the problem the RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
 is causing the issue...is there a way to do this rule except contact