# Why my open cart htaccess rule not redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

In reference to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184712/why-is-my-htaccess-rule-not-rewriting-the-url
```

i am using the above solution and it is working fine for me but when i use to write a rule for url having ? in it it got fail

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/popup/popup.css\?ver\=4.3$ /contact-us  [L,QSA]
```

the above rule is not working. what i am missing here ?

Comment: that's because query strings are not part of the url. you can't test for them like that. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ver=4.3`-type stuff is what you need.

Comment: did you mean RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/popup/popup.css{QUERY_STRING}ver=4.3$ /contact-us  [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ver=4.3$
RewriteRule ^wp-content/plugins/popup/popup.css$ /contact-us  [L,QSA]
```